# COUNT em multiplas tabelas do mysql

Tags: mysql, select, vb.net

Boa tarde, alguém sabe me informar oque á de errado no codigo abaixo ?

Pois ele apenas faz a verificação count em uma tabela as demais ele ignora.

o Insert está correto porem o "Select Count" nao verifica todas apenas o primeiro comando.

segue o codigo:

```
'inicia uma FOR para verificação e impedir inserts de duplicados.

For r As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

Dim resultquery As String = "SELECT 

(SELECT COUNT(cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf) FROM cnpjcpf WHERE cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf ='" & DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(7).Value & "'),

(SELECT COUNT(mov_identificacao) FROM movimento WHERE mov_identificacao ='" & DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'),

(SELECT COUNT(imov_mov_identificacao) FROM imovimento WHERE imov_mov_identificacao ='" & DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "')"

 command = New MySqlCommand(resultquery, sqlcoon)
 resultquery = command.ExecuteScalar()

   If resultquery = 0 Then

' insere os dados do datagridview na tabela do banco de dados

  Dim Query As String = '"insert into cnpjcpf (cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf) values(@cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf);" +
                         "insert into movimento (mov_identificacao,mov_protocolo,mov_destinatario,mov_endereco,mov_bairro,mov_cep,mov_datadoc,mov_cnpj_cpf,mov_cli_codigo,mov_dataprocessa,mov_datavencimento) values(@mov_identificacao, @mov_protocolo, @mov_destinatario, @mov_endereco, @mov_bairro, @mov_cep, @mov_datadoc, @mov_cnpj_cpf, @mov_cli_codigo, @mov_dataprocessa, @mov_datavencimento);" +
                         "insert into imovimento (imov_mov_identificacao,imov_mov_protocolo,imov_dataprocessa) values(@imov_mov_identificacao,@imov_mov_protocolo,@imov_dataprocessa);"
                    Dim CmdSalvarItens As New MySqlCommand(Query, sqlcoon)

     'EXECUTA O INSERT NA TABELA CNPJ/CPF
      CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(7).Value

       'EXECUTA O INSERT NA TABELA MOVIMENTOS
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_identificacao", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Identificação").Value
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_protocolo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Protocolo").Value
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_destinatario", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Destinatario").Value
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_endereco", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Endereço").Value
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_bairro", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Bairro").Value
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_cep", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Cep").Value
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_datadoc", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dinicio
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_cnpj_cpf", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("CNPF/CPF").Value
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_cli_codigo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtcod.Text
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_dataprocessa", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dfim
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_datavencimento", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = ddata

       'EXECUTA O INSERT NA TABELA IMOVIMENTOS
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@imov_mov_identificacao", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Identificação").Value
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@imov_mov_protocolo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Protocolo").Value
       CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@imov_dataprocessa", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dfim


          CmdSalvarItens.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Else

        End If

       Next
```

Alguem pode me dizer oque esta errado no (string - ResultQuery) onde esta sendo feito os 3 select count??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que isto resolve o seu problema:

```
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
Dim CmdSalvarItens As MySqlCommand
Dim Query As String
Dim resultquery As String

Dim strCPF As String
Dim strMovimentos As String
Dim strImovimentos As String

'inicia uma FOR para verificação e impedir inserts de duplicados.
For r As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    strCPF = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(7).Value.ToString
    strMovimentos = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value.ToString
    strImovimentos = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value.ToString

    resultquery = "SELECT 
        (SELECT COUNT(cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf) FROM cnpjcpf WHERE cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf ='" & strCPF & "'),
        (SELECT COUNT(mov_identificacao) FROM movimento WHERE mov_identificacao ='" & strMovimentos & "'),
        (SELECT COUNT(imov_mov_identificacao) FROM imovimento WHERE imov_mov_identificacao ='" & strImovimentos & "')"

    command = New MySqlCommand(resultquery, sqlcoon)
    reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    reader.Read()

    Dim objs(3) As Object
    Dim quant As Integer = reader.GetValues(objs)

    'TABELA CNPJ/CPF
    If objs(0) = 0 Then
        'insere os dados do datagridview na tabela do banco de dados
        Query = "insert into cnpjcpf (cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf) values(@cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf);"

        CmdSalvarItens = New MySqlCommand(Query, sqlcoon)
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@cnpjcpf_cnpjcpf", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strCPF

        CmdSalvarItens.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If

    'TABELA MOVIMENTOS
    If objs(1) = 0 Then
        'insere os dados do datagridview na tabela do banco de dados
        Query = "insert into movimento (mov_identificacao,mov_protocolo,mov_destinatario,mov_endereco,mov_bairro,mov_cep,mov_datadoc,mov_cnpj_cpf,mov_cli_codigo,mov_dataprocessa,mov_datavencimento) values(@mov_identificacao, @mov_protocolo, @mov_destinatario, @mov_endereco, @mov_bairro, @mov_cep, @mov_datadoc, @mov_cnpj_cpf, @mov_cli_codigo, @mov_dataprocessa, @mov_datavencimento);"

        CmdSalvarItens = New MySqlCommand(Query, sqlcoon)
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_identificacao", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Identificação").Value
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_protocolo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Protocolo").Value
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_destinatario", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Destinatario").Value
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_endereco", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Endereço").Value
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_bairro", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Bairro").Value
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_cep", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Cep").Value
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_datadoc", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dinicio
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_cnpj_cpf", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("CNPF/CPF").Value
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_cli_codigo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtcod.Text
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_dataprocessa", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dfim
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@mov_datavencimento", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = ddata

        CmdSalvarItens.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If

    'TABELA CNPJ/CPF
    If objs(2) = 0 Then
        'insere os dados do datagridview na tabela do banco de dados
        Query = "insert into imovimento (imov_mov_identificacao,imov_mov_protocolo,imov_dataprocessa) values(@imov_mov_identificacao,@imov_mov_protocolo,@imov_dataprocessa);"

        CmdSalvarItens = New MySqlCommand(Query, sqlcoon)
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@imov_mov_identificacao", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Identificação").Value
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@imov_mov_protocolo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Protocolo").Value
        CmdSalvarItens.Parameters.Add("@imov_dataprocessa", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dfim

        CmdSalvarItens.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If

    reader.Close()
Next
```

O problema estava no facto de estar a utilizar `ExecuteScalar()`, que apenas lhe traz úm único valor, quando na verdade queremos trazer **3**.

Posto isto, utilizamos o `ExecuteReader()` para ler todos os resultados (que neste caso é apenas uma linha com 3 colunas) e depois vamos um a um executar as *queries*.

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno João , mas ainda não deu certo o seu exemplo. mesmo eu modificando o código da maneira que me aconselhou. retorna o seguinte error : If myreader.GetInt32(1) = 0 Then --> "You have specified an invalid column ordinal." e tive que acrescentar um Reader.Close() posterior do Reader.read() senão apontava que jã tinha um Reader sendo utilizado.

Comment: Resposta editada, tinha alguns erros! Experimente de novo :)

Comment: João Permaneceu o error. eu fiz um teste. Comentei todas as linhas onde tem ' Tabela movimento e Imovimentos . e deixei apenas o IF da tabela cnpj/cpf. e entao acrescentei um reader.close() ficando assim ->  If reader.GetInt32(0) = 0 Then
                    reader.Close()  - Funcionou perfeitamente. descometei o IF da tabela Movimentos e tentei fazer o mesmo porém. deu error o mesmo error (""You have specified an invalid column ordinal." Acredito eu que falta apenas um detalhe para funcionar.

Comment: Se colocar a _query_ no SQL o que é que lhe devolve?

Comment: da maneira que vc me deu sem eu alterar devolve: 
Já existe um DataReader aberto associado a esta conexão que deve ser fechado primeiro. - por isso acrescente reader.close() pra ver se funcionava. quando tem apenas um IF reader.close() resolve. quando eu acrescente mais um não funciona mais.

Comment: Não, não era isso. Se pegar na _query_ SQL resultante da variável `resultquery` e colocar diretamente no SQL, que resultado lhe dá? Devolve-lhe 3 colunas com números inteiros?

Comment: sim retorna 3 numero . porém por serem os primeiros dados a serem inseridos. retorna ( 0 , 0 , 0). Acredito que o error seja que Alguma parte do código antes ou depois do IF o Reader precisa ser fechado. tanto que se remover os comentarios dos 2 IF ' tabela movimentos e imovimentos e acrescenter Reader.close() o error só vem no terceiro if.

Comment: Resposta editada com código diferente.

Comment: João,reformulei o código de acordo com a alteração que você acabou de fazer. Retornou o error no  CmdSalvarItens.ExecuteNonQuery() do Primeiro IF ( If objs(0) = 0 Then) error : "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first "

Comment: joão conseguir resolver, acrescentando o Read.close()  Dim quant As Integer = reader.GetValues(objs) resolveu o problema , fiz a alteração no código que você editou. muito obrigado mesmo pela solução, pelo tempo e atenção.